# pandas.to_datetime ERROR

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to convert the time column to datetime format.

Time

30/May/2013 06:00:41 -0600

```
import pandas as pd
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Time'))
```

But it always gives the following error.What is the problem with the code? :(

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-9219cf10d027> in <module>()
----> 1 df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Time'))

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'
```

Comment: So, I find `to_datetime` method in `pd.DatetimeIndex` class. I don't use pandas before, but can't you get `pd.DatetimeIndex` object from `df.pop('Time')`? Or, maybe, convert it?

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The `to_datetime` function was [introduced in 0.8.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html#time-series-changes-and-improvements), so you'll have to upgrade your pandas to use it.
Ideally to the [latest stable version](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html).

Answer (score -1):

Use set_index to set the time column as the index, and then convert the `Index` to `DateTimeIndex`:

```
df = df.set_index('Time')

df.index = df.index.to_datetime()
```