# Attribute error using the quandl module in python27: module object has no attribute 'to_date_time'

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

For the following code

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd 

api_key = open('quandlapikey.txt','r').read()

df = quandl.get('FMAC/HPI_AK',authtoken=api_key)

print(df.head())
```

I am getting this error:

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Quandl-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/quandl/get.py",
>   line 63, in get
>       return data.to_pandas()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Quandl-3.1.0-py2.7.egg/quandl/model/data_mixin.py",
>   line 20, in to_pandas
>       df[self.column_names[0]] = df[self.column_names[0]].apply(pd.to_datetime) AttributeError:
>   'module' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your `pandas` version.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910795/pandas-to-datetime-error) answer:

> The to_datetime function was introduced in 0.8.0, so you'll have to
>   upgrade your pandas to use it. Ideally to the latest stable version.

Try using:

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
```

Comment: What version does it show? You can check it using `pd.__version__`.

Comment: but if i try to upgrade, it shows it is already the newest version

Comment: Thank you, it helped. i just needed to use sudo before. thank you for your help